# How to do I visualize this data using ggplot2- output of a function with changing weights?

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2, 3d, visualization

The output below is a function with changing weights:
Think of them as age, height and category where the sum of the weights for age, height and category is always 1. The table contains a plot of the function output changing weights of age and height from 0 to 10 and the third, i.e., category is (1- age - height).

The result of the top left corner [1,1] is the output of the function giving weights : age=0, height = 0, category = 1

The result of the top right corner [1,11] is the output of the function giving weights : age=0, height = 1, category = 0

The result of the bottom left corner [11,1] is the output of the function giving weights : age=1, height = 0, category = 0

All values where NULL are not possible, where w(age) + w(height) > 1

```
      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10] [,11]
 [1,] 1662 3571 3571 3571 3571 3571 7891 8027 8045 8055  8080 
 [2,] 3842 3594 3613 3611 3611 7957 8017 8031 8059 8081  NULL 
 [3,] 3842 3667 3594 3594 3613 7103 8038 8054 8085 NULL  NULL 
 [4,] 3842 3678 3594 3594 7056 7124 8053 8078 NULL NULL  NULL 
 [5,] 3842 3678 3667 3606 7102 8053 8078 NULL NULL NULL  NULL 
 [6,] 3842 3678 3668 7100 7139 8078 NULL NULL NULL NULL  NULL 
 [7,] 3842 3698 3702 7124 7164 NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL  NULL 
 [8,] 3842 3698 7102 7164 NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL  NULL 
 [9,] 3842 3783 7164 NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL  NULL 
[10,] 3842 7174 NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL  NULL 
[11,] 3968 NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL  NULL `
```

How would I plot this on a 3-D graph using ggplot2? (I'm new to using ggplot2)

Comment: You want a 3D graph? With ggplot2? Those two things don't go together -- so what's more important, making a 3D plot? Or using ggplot?

Comment: Yikes! Sorry, I did not know that. I guess my question is what would be the appropriate 3-D plot and code to generate it.

Comment: An alternative to a 3-D plot might be a [ternary Plot](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ternary_plot)

Comment: Thank you, I accomplished this using a ternary plot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As MrFlick pointed out, ggplots don't do 3-D. For this purpose, a ternary diagram with a heat map would be adequate.

Solution using ggtern:

First reformat the data into a dataframe 'df' which has the values of age, height and category and the function 'rec'

```
ggtern(df, aes(age, height, cat)) + geom_point(aes(colour=rec)) + 
scale_color_gradient(low='green', high='red')
```

[image: Ternary heatmap (function values different from original)]